# Gap between divs w/ padding 0?

Tags: css, html

I've been searching around for a while (for the answer) with no success, so I guess I did "my homework"...

So basically I've a gap between 2 divs.
[You can see it here.](http://8ahonlap.net23.net/)

Comment: Your HTML is ALL over the place, tags randomly opening and closing, multiple head and body tags, script outside of the HTML entirely. You'll possibly just be seeing the results of that as the browser scrabbles to render your page.

Comment: Your code is kind of a mess. Have a look in the source code view of Firefox and try to fix the indicated errors (red marked tags).

Comment: I know, this is an old site of mine, and I'm currently re-doing it. First I replaced the tables with divs.

Comment: @JeffWatkins Also, I did the most pages with Dreamweaver so it'll be a pain in da ass to remove all those tags. (php include)

Comment: @SevenofNine Sure, I feel your pain (having had to do similar exercises in the past), but until your HTML passes a validator, you may see some freaky side effects on various browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on your content class

```
.content {
  background: url("panel.png");
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  float: left; /*new style*/
  width: 100%; /*new style*/
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Give `overflow:hidden` to your `.bigtext`, like this:

```css
.bigtext{
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

This problem is called "collapsing margins".

Check this http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html

Answer (score 2):

The gap is caused by the `p` element.
You need to take the margins off - browsers default behaviour is to add 1em before and after the paragraph.

If you use google chrome, you can right click and goto **inspect element**. From there you can see what default behaviours have been applied to certain elements on the page. You can even see visually what space has been created by margins. Your gap was one of them. =)

See screenshot below - this is showing the margin applied to another `p` element.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try `margin: 0;` for those divs.

Comment: No effect, you can check it too. :[

Answer (score 0):

you can hack it by applying `margin-top:-23px` to the `.content` div